# meta_query not filering but meta_key works fine

Tags: meta-query

Ok, I feel like I have to be overlooking something very simple with this.  I have done this so many times but I cannot figure out why my meta_key, meta_value works but my meta_query does not.

Let's start with what works:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'paged'          => ( int ) get_query_var( 'paged', 1 ),
    'post_type'      => array( 'page', ' post' ),
    'post_status'    => array( 'publish' ),
    'category_name'  => $sc['category'],     
    'posts_per_page' => $sc['number_posts'],
    'order'          => $sc['order'],
    'orderby'        => $sc['order_by'],
    'meta_key'   => 'product_post_id',
'meta_value'     => $sc['parent_page_id']
    );
```

The variable passed through the shortcode with the 'parent_page_id' = the meta_key and displays the correct pages.  However, if I change it to this:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'paged'          => ( int ) get_query_var( 'paged', 1 ),
    'post_type'      => array( 'page', ' post' ),
    'post_status'    => array( 'publish' ),
    'category_name'  => $sc['category'],     
    'posts_per_page' => $sc['number_posts'],
    'order'          => $sc['order'],
    'orderby'        => $sc['order_by'],
'meta_query'     => array(
                array(
               'key' => 'product_post_id',
               'value' => $sc['parent_page_id']
                  )
              )
             );
```

It does not work.   Even if I add the 'compare' => '=' to the meta_query, it does not work.

Any ideas?  Thank you so much for your help with this.

Comment: in `order` or `order_by`, do you use `meta_value` ?

Comment: Keep in mind that doing a `meta_query` is obscenely expensive/slow, it's a massively expensive thing to do, and it's super super easy to avoid. In your case, simply setting the product as the parent, or using a taxonomy where the names of the terms are the product post IDs would lead to stupendous performance gains